# How to create a library with CMakeLists.txt and include it in another program?

Tags: c, cmake, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I'm new to C/C++ development and I'm struggling with CMakeLists.txt in CLion IDE.

I can't create a library (static or shared) that I can #include in another program.

I have this kind of structure :

```
src/
 |
 |---> utilities/
 |         |---> CMakeLists.txt
 |         |---> utilties.h
 |         |
 |         |---> file_utilities/
 |         |            |---> file_utilities.h
 |         |            |---> file_utilities.c
 |        ...
 |
 |---> my_app
          |---> CMakeLists.txt
          |---> main.c
```

I have generated a libutilities.so and a libutilities.a. In my main.c file, it works if I do a `#include "../utilities/utilities.h"` or `#include "../utilities/file_utilities/file_utilities.h"`.

Worse, if I create another project, with another program and link my libutilities.so, the link seems to work, but still can't include my headers.

I've tried many configuration, many options in CMakeLists.txt but it has never worked until now.

Here is the CMakeLists.txt that I use for my library. I'm quite sure the problem is in this file.

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
    project(utilities VERSION 1.0.0)

    set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

    link_libraries(pthread)
    link_libraries(ssl)
    link_libraries(crypto)

    find_package(CURL REQUIRED)
    include_directories(${CURL_INCLUDE_DIRS})

    file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES RELATIVES "*.c")
    file(GLOB_RECURSE HEADERS RELATIVES "*.h")

    add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})

    set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
            PUBLIC_HEADER "${HEADERS}"
            ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "lib"
            LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "lib"
            OUTPUT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})

    target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC .)

    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CURL_LIBRARIES})

    include(GNUInstallDirs)
    install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
            LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
            ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
            PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/${PROJECT_NAME})
```

I'd like to have something more like `#include <utilities/utilties.h>` as it's a library. But I can't make it works.

In the example I provided, the library is a simple "utils" library, but I have to create more that I'll have to deliver and be integrated in another program than mine.

Comment: It is better to provide **absolute path** for `target_include_directories`. According to [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/command/target_include_directories.html), relative paths are allowed only for `$<INSTALL_INTERFACE>` expression. You don't show `my_app/CMakeLists.txt` script. but assuming it has `target_link_libraries(<exe> utilities)`, the things should work.

Comment: It's better, but it's still not working as I wish. In the current project, I'm now able to `#include <utilities.h>`, or directly `#include <file_utilities/file_utilities.h>`. But I still can't use it in another program with my *.so* or *.a* library. Can I use those built in the cmake-build-debug folder ?

Comment: If you want to provide header files for **other project**, normal way is to **install** those header files. Then, in the other project you just need to ajust include directories to that installed location. You may find [CMake packaging tutorial](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/manual/cmake-packages.7.html) useful for your purpose.

Comment: I would just recommend using `add_library(utilities)` as you have now, and just inside `my_app/CMakeLists.txt` add `add_subdirectory(utlities ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../utilities)` and simple `target_link_libraries(my_app PUBLIC utilities)`. There is no need for `install()`, which is harder to maintain then just simple `add_library()`.

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest reading [this article](https://pabloariasal.github.io/2018/02/19/its-time-to-do-cmake-right/), in which a fictional library target is created, starting from project structure to installing/exporting. From my understanding, the author has exactly the same goal as you do. The article has cleared up a lot of things for me when I started out. I also recomend the project structure laid out within.

Project structure:

```
libjsonutils
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── include
│   └── jsonutils
│       └── json_utils.h
├── src
│   ├── file_utils.h
│   └── json_utils.cpp
└── test
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    └── src
        └── test_main.cpp
```

Specifically, you will want to take a look at [Targets and Properties](https://pabloariasal.github.io/2018/02/19/its-time-to-do-cmake-right/#targets-and-properties), where generator expressions are used to differentiate between the include dir at build time, and when installed:

```
target_include_directories(JSONUtils
    PUBLIC 
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>    
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
    PRIVATE
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src
)
```

The install process and exporting/importing of targets is explained a little later in [This is how you do CMake](https://pabloariasal.github.io/2018/02/19/its-time-to-do-cmake-right/#this-is-how-you-do-cmake). What the author wants to do is be able to use the library in other cmake projects (e.g. a target called "example"), simply by doing the following:

```
find_package(JSONUtils 1.0 REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(example JSONUtils::JSONUtils)
```

In order to make this work, you will need to install and export the library. The author encourages this for installation:

```
include(GNUInstallDirs)
install(TARGETS JSONUtils
    EXPORT jsonutils-export
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
)
```

And this for exporting:

```
install(EXPORT jsonutils-targets
  FILE
    JSONUtilsTargets.cmake
  NAMESPACE
    JSONUtils::
  DESTINATION
    ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/JSONUtils
)
```

The export will place a file named findJsonUtils.cmake in the given destination. This file will be what you need to import the library in other projects by using the find_package mechanism.

All code samples in this post taken from Pablo Arias' linked article.

Comment: On Stack Overflow we want the answer to be useful even without following the links it has. But you answer currently has a little sence without links. Please, add at least some information from the links your provide **directly** into the question post.

Answer (score 0):

Your CMakeLists.txt is **inside** `utilities` try to use this.

`src/utilities/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
  PUBLIC
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/..>
)
```

For the app you should have something like:
`src/my_app/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE utilities)
```

and you should have simple
`src/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_subdirectory(utilities)
add_subdirectory(my_app)
```